# How to observe model changes on form level

Tags: angular, angular6, event-listener, angular-forms

In Angular6, I've got a template-driven form that I want to observe for changes *after* they have been applied to the model. It seems the only event I can subscribe to is [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#valueChanges):

```
myForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(change => {...})
```

At that point of time, the model hasn't been updated yet, though. Any ideas (without using `setTimeout`)?

Comment: Where do you watch for `form.valueChanges`?. I mean which method?

Comment: 1.-subscribe after create the form, 2.Use the variable "change", not the values (I think that in Angular 6 is corrected, but I'm not sure)

Comment: @AmitChigadani in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: @Eliseo 1. I did, 2. how does the _change_ variable help me? It's just a map of input directive names to their values, but I want to access the updated model. Imo `valueChanges` is the wrong observable to subscribe to anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I don't read your question completly. must be this.myForm.get('control-name').valueChanges.subscribe(change=>{console.log(change)}). If you want to control any change, can write  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(change=>{console.log(change)}). AFTER you create the form. IT's about another question but if you want to see an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-161pb9-pxor9v?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts